# Android studio AVD amanger fails to install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

When installing emulator in android studio I get the following error

*An error occurred during installation: File too large.
Failed to install Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image!*

Stacktrace for the same in console is as below

```
    [ 577974]   WARN - ectedPackagesStep$CustomLogger - An error occurred during installation: File too large. 
java.io.IOException: File too large
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:326)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at com.android.repository.util.InstallerUtil.unzip(InstallerUtil.java:122)
    at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.install(BasicInstaller.java:96)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.wizard.InstallSelectedPackagesStep$InstallTask.run(InstallSelectedPackagesStep.java:242)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

System Configuration:

- **Os** : Centos7
- **Android Studio** : 2.1.3
- **Java** : jdk 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Got the fix, actual problem was the ulimit for file size was 1G and the file being unzipped was 2G size so it was throwing file size too large (core dumped)

**-rw-rw-r--. 1 shubhendu shubhendu 2.0G Aug 27 17:28 userdata.img**

Increasing the ulimit to 4G solved the problem.

For Centos7 the ulimit for user can be increased in below file:

```
sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf
shubhendu   hard  fsize  4096000
```

Comment: So you just left the problem for future ;)